# Correct way of handling high-volume messages in Google's Dataflow of Pub/Sub to BigQuery template

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

As the title notes, we are using dataflow to send messages from PubSub to BigQuery using the standard template. The dataflow's error looks like this:

> Maximum allowed row size exceeded. Allowed: 1048576 Row size: 2148312

And yas, I know it's all about streaming insert limitations.

From time to time, we are seeing high volume messages. Even though in common, most of them are far from being that big and it's ok for us to lose those, but we'd like to be aware of them. Is there any way of doing so? As a result, we'd like to receive a row stored in the deadletter table, and truncated one could work.

I've tried to rewrite the UDF function so it returns an empty result if a message got is too big, but, as expected, it's just lost, and same does any piece of information if such happens, which could be harmful to us if it becomes a common problem.

Throwing an error also doesn't work, because the error is still there, yet on another cell. Moreover, dataflow's continuously retrying to insert the record. So, for 2-3 such messages, we got like >300 worker errors.

What could be done to save some data about that, yet get rid of the error?

Comment: Can you detect the size of the message before sending it to BigQuery?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, yes. There is an a-la middleware, but due to high load we'd like to move all the filtering and validation to the UDF. However, if there is no other way to do so, it can be done there

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a Dataflow template, you could write a simple job and take care of error handling, as per your requirement.

You can leverage the OOB connectors to write your job.

**1. PubSubIO.Read** - for reading messages

**2. BigQuery.Write** - for writing to big query. It returns WriteResult and use getFailedInserts to get PCollection of failed records. Then you could insert these records into your error table or handle it appropriately.

Alternatively, for point 2 we could also write a custom PTransform and use BigQuery client libraries for writing. This would provide a more granular level of control to handle exceptions. However, if possible try to use BigQueryIO only as it is optimized and tested.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write these data into BigQuery in streaming mode. So you have 2 solutions

- Write the too large message into files on GCS and periodically load them into BigQuery
- Write the too large message into PubSub, and periodically trigger a functions (or Cloud Run) to flush the PubSub queue and create a load job into BigQuery.

In both case, I mention "periodically" because you are limited to 1000 loads job per days and if you perform a load job on each too large message, you maybe reach this limit (You have to evaluate the risk of this, it's just a piece of advice).

If you have a lot of large message, take care to not break the Cloud Function/Cloud Run memory limit when you flush your PubSub messages.

For saving time and resources, I prefer to filter the message sizes before submitting it to BigQuery. However, the @Nirley solution, that I didn't know (Thanks!!+1), can also work.